# PHP Hooks add_action() do_action() are not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

My code works if I remove the hooks `add_action()` and remove `'action': 'contact'` In AJAX. In this case it returns **'Success'**.
But once I add hooks to email.php and `'action': 'contact'` it stops to return me anything. Could you give me an advice how to fix it? I believe I do it exactly as in the documentation.

This is my simple code:

**Email.php:**

```
<?php

 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact', 'contact' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact', 'contact' );

 function contact() {
  echo 'Success';
  wp_die();
 }

 ?>
```

**Functions.php:**

```
function load_script()
{
  wp_enqueue_script( 'contact_form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/contact_form/contact_form.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'contact_form', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/email.php')
  );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script');
```

**Contact_form.js:**

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '.mybtn' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              'action': 'contact'
          },
          success: function( response ) {
              console.log('The server responded: ',response);
          },
        });
   });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Then I tried just to remove 'action': 'contact' and
**change Email.php to:**

```
<?php

add_action( 'contact', 'contactme' );

function contactme() {
  echo 'Success';
}

do_action('contact');

?>
```

And it doesn't work!
**But the next code works perfectly:**

```
<?php
  echo 'Success';
?>
```

AJAX returns Success.

**I also tried to add 10 and also 1 at the end of add_action:**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact', 'contact', 10 );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact', 'contact', 10 );

function contact() {
  echo 'Success';
  wp_die();
}

?>
```

But it hasn't helped.

Do you know why my hooks don't work?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When using ajax in WordPress we do not call the file that stores the function you want to run. Instead `admin-ajax.php` is called.

Your **email.php** file will be as following, but you must include it in your **function.php**. Or just put this function inside the **function.php** file. Also note that every function which is going to be called by ajax request must end with [wp_die()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/).

```
function contact() {
  echo 'Success';
  wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact', 'contact' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact', 'contact' );
```

Next in `load_script()` add `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` in `'ajaxurl'`.

```
function load_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'contact_form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/contact_form/contact_form.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'contact_form', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script');
```

**contact_form.js** will almost be the same.

```
(function($){
  $('.mybtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action: 'contact'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
 });
})(jQuery);
```