# Why does an add_action hook lead to 500 error?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code:

```
<?php

add_action( 'contactme', 'contact', 10 );

function contact() {
  echo 'Success';
  wp_die();
}

do_action('contactme');

?>
```

It generates a 500 error.

If I remove everything except `echo 'Success';` The code starts to work well.

Do you know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

I am attaching the logs:

```
Error getting response code, most likely a stopped request

Array
(
    [url] => https://website.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1654995883.2758231163024902343750
    [args] => Array
        (
            [method] => POST
            [timeout] => 0.01
            [redirection] => 5
            [httpversion] => 1.0
            [user-agent] => WordPress/6.0; https://website.com
            [reject_unsafe_urls] => 
            [blocking] => 
            [headers] => Array
                (
                )

            [cookies] => Array
                (
                )

            [body] => 
            [compress] => 
            [decompress] => 1
            [sslverify] => 
            [sslcertificates] => /home/myname/website.com/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt
            [stream] => 
            [filename] => 
            [limit_response_size] => 
            [time_start] => 1654995883.2794
            [_redirection] => 5
            [time_stop] => 1654995884.2844
            [duration] => 1004.9660205841
        )

    [r] => Array
        (
            [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [body] => [omitted]
            [response] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 
                    [message] => 
                )

            [cookies] => Array
                (
                )

            [filename] => 
        )

    [class] => Requests
    [stack_trace] => Array
        (
            [0] => Debug_Bar_WP_Http->after_http_request
            [1] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
            [2] => WP_Hook->do_action
            [3] => do_action('http_api_debug')
            [4] => WP_Http->request
            [5] => WP_Http->post
            [6] => wp_remote_post
            [7] => spawn_cron
            [8] => _wp_cron
            [9] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
            [10] => WP_Hook->do_action
            [11] => do_action('wp_loaded')
            [12] => require_once('wp-settings.php')
            [13] => require_once('wp-config.php')
            [14] => require_once('wp-load.php')
            [15] => require_once('wp-admin/admin.php')
        )

)
```

Unfortunately at the moment I am not so proficient to understand by these logs, why the error occurs. I'll be glad if you give me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [wp_die()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) then you'll see that its default response is 200 for Ajax requests and 500 otherwise. So just remove `wp_die()`.

```
add_action( 'contactme', 'contact', 10 );

function contact() {
  echo 'Success';
}

do_action('contactme');
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the response. Unfortunately the truth is that I get a 500 Error even if I remove wp_die(). I already tried to do it many times and for some reason it still shows me a 500 error.

Comment: is this file being called using ajax? as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581816/php-hooks-add-action-do-action-are-not-working